Fmpeg capturing webcam and audio: audio stops playing towards the end of the video
This is the command: ffmpeg -f alsa -i default -i /dev/video0 eatmyass.mp4 Playing the recording during the last 5 seconds there is no audio.
So now i need the audio to perfectly match the video, what should i do?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
